# WPF ListBox selected item not changed while using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

My listbox is binded to an items source and selecteditem property is also binded. Most of my work is being done in selecteditem property. Actually I have two listboxes, for each item in first list box there are some child items in the collection. Against all the items that are selected in first listbox, their child items are supposed to be added in the second list box.

Problem is Selecting the item(by checking the checkbox) does not raise the SelectedItem property changed

XAML for my listbox controls are

```
 <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Charts,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox Content="{Binding ChartName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChartSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsTrackSelected}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding TrackName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My Chart Selection Changed property in view model is

```
  public ChartSourceForMultipleSelection SelectedChart
    {
        get { return _selectedChart; }
        set
        {
            _selectedChart = value;
            ChartSelectionChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedChart");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This binding doesn't make any sense:</strike>

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsTrackSelected,
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
```

This attempts to bind to a property `IsTrackSelected` on the outer `ListBoxItem`, but no such property exists.  It doesn't look like you need a `RelativeSource` here, provided `IsTrackSelected` is a property of the underlying data item.

Also, I'm not sure why you're a `ListBox` for the tracks collection; it looks like your concepts of track selection is separate from the `ListBox` concept of a selected item.  Why not use a simple `ItemsControl` instead?

As to your primary problem, the `CheckBox` in the item template is eating the mouse/focus events that would normally tell the `ListBox` to select the parent `ListBoxItem` when clicked.  You can manually update the selection state of a `ListBoxItem` whenever its inner `CheckBox` receives keyboard focus.

Add `GotKeyboardFocus="OnChartCheckBoxGotKeyboardFocus"` to the `CheckBox` your chart list item template, give the chart list box a name, e.g., `x:Name="ChartsList"`, and write the handler in the code behind:

```
private void OnChartCheckBoxGotKeyboardFocus(
    object sender,
    KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    if (checkBox == null)
        return;

    var listBoxItem = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(ChartsList, checkBox)
                      as ListBoxItem;
    if (listBoxItem != null)
        listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: How you are planning to  get notification in view model of checkbox checked/unchecked. As the binded property is part of an entity and it does not raise any event in VM.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the `SelectedItem` binding because it was off-screen.  In that case, my previous comments about using an `ItemsControl` only apply to the second track list.  When you toggle a checkbox in the first list, does the parent `ListBoxItem` become selected?

Comment: No the parent item does not get selected and this is the real problem

Comment: Gotcha.  Can you clarify one thing for me real quick: do you allow multiple items in the chart list to be checked?  In other words, is the check box state independent of the selection in the `ListBox`?

Comment: Yes, user could select multiple items. I have tried selectionmode=multiple and mode=twoway and updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged on selecteditem property.

Comment: Right, but conceptually, do you want multiple chart items to be checked, while only displaying the track items for the *selected* chart item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63513/discussion-between-megamind-and-mike-strobel).

Comment: Sadly, StackOverflow chat is blocked at my office.

Comment: I have tried it but rejected by client as it is not pure MVVM.

Comment: There is not an MVVM solution to this because it is not a model/data issue; it is a presentation layer issue, and it specific to the view design.  The code behind is the appropriate place to handle this.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your effort, if you find any better solution in future, please post it here.